# Dynamically Created Events

Tags: c#, events

I am wondering if when I create a mouse leave event like the below mentioned code whether it actually creates a method in memory like a design time mouse enter event. I am using WinForms in C#. There is a loop which initializes the `iRow,iColumn` values into a 8x8 grid of panels.

```
chessBoardPanels[iRow, iColumn].MouseLeave += (s, e) => {
                    (s as Panel).BackColor = temp;};
```

Comment: What else could it be doing?

Comment: Well what I actually want is to create is mouse enter an mouse leave events which would end up being something along the lines of:    chessBoardPanels[value1,value27]_mouse enter(object sender, EventArgs e)    which could populate a label control with a value chessboard

Comment: like g7 on a chess board.  The value1 and value2 values would be associated with another 2D array which would give the output into a A1,A2..B3,...like the position on a chess board

Comment: That's not a dynamically created event, it's an anonymous event handler.  The difference in terms there is key.  It's not dynamic; it's statically defined at compile time what the event handler is, what it's type is, etc.  It's simply anonymous in that it doesn't have a name, but other than not having a name (that you could use anyway), it's like any other method.  Second, it's not an event, it's an event handler.  The event is what is invoking the handler.  These distinctions are very important.

Comment: Go see your other question.. I posted some code that might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a method in memory. When you use a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx) you are passing a reference to an anonymous method.